# Multi-threading(Maybe Threads not running at my will.)

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to perform a single-task(finding sum of 1st 100 positive integers) using multiple threads in java. That's why I'm using a single run() method. I've seen multiple sites which shows single-tasking using multithreading by using only single run method(they put the task in same run() method), but I found that it will only only do same task multiple times everytime a new thread is started. That is why I'm using a static variable count.
The task is divided into 3 sub-tasks-

1. sum 1 to 50(will be performed by thread1 object)
2. sum 51 to 75(will be performed by thread2 object)
3. sum 76 to 100(will be performed by thread1 object)
   So this is the code which I wrote.

```
//In this single tasking will be done using multiple thread
public class SingleTasking extends Thread {
    static int count=0;
    static int sum=0;                                  //global variable to store total sum
    //private static long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    public void run(){
        if(count==0) {
        //System.out.println(getName());
        sum+=sum1to50();
        count++;
        //currentThread().stop();
    }
    else if(count==1) {
        //System.out.println(getName());
        sum+=sum51to75();
        count++;
        //currentThread().stop();
    }
    else {
        //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()); 
        sum+=sum76to100();
        System.out.println("Sum of 1st 100 integers:"+sum);
        count++;
    }
    }
    int sum1to50() {               //1st part of the task
        int sum=0;                      //local variable to store sum 1 to 50
    for(int i=1;i<=50;i++)
        sum+=i;
    return sum;
    }
    int sum51to75() {              //2nd part of the task
    int sum=0;          //local variable to store sum 51 to 75
    for(int i=51;i<=75;i++)
        sum+=i;
    return sum;
    }
    int sum76to100() {             //3rd part of the task
    int sum=0;          //local variable to store sum 76 to 100
    for(int i=76;i<=100;i++)
        sum+=i;
    return sum;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Task is to find sum of first 100 integers.");
        System.out.println("1st thread will find sum of 1-50.");
        System.out.println("2nd thread will find sum of 51-75.");
        System.out.println("3rd thread will find sum of 76-100.");
        SingleTasking thread1=new SingleTasking();    
        SingleTasking thread2=new SingleTasking();    
        SingleTasking thread3=new SingleTasking();    
        //thread1.setPriority(9);
        //thread2.setPriority(5);
        //thread3.setPriority(1);
        thread1.start();
        //thread1.stop();
        thread2.start();
        //thread2.stop();
        thread3.start();
        //System.out.println("Sum of 1st 100 integers:"+sum);
        //You can't print sum here as no priority is set to threads 
        //and therefore it can print any value of static variable sum
        //like 0,sum1to50, sum1to75, sum 76to100 depending on 
        //default main thread execution order.
        //Below are the statements to calculate sum
        //long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //System.out.println("It took " + (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds");
    }
}
```

although the output is what I needed most of the times, but sometimes it differs too.

I tried many things(commented in the code) like giving priority to threads, sleeping threads, stopping them but nothing works.

Can you explain me why it not working properly?
It would be helpful if you  give me a better solution.
I do not want to threads run in a particular order but what I want is a single thread will perform a single sub-task(i.e. call any of the sum1to50(), sum51to75(),sum76to100() methods).

Comment: You rely on each thread to finish their job before increasing the count, but what if the thread takes a bit longer to finish before the next one starts? By then the count might not have increased. Create a constructor for `SingleTasking` and pass the count there. Or better yet, pass the range for the thread to calculate. That way you reduce the amount of code

Comment: And to ensure that each thread is finished, use `thread1.join();` for each one you create

Comment: Hey @XtremeBaumer  thanks for your help but I have a doubt that isn't it the thread job to increase the count? or is it like that when one thread is started then JVM donot look for it to complete it just go to execute the next statements?

Comment: The main thread and every other thread you create are running separate from each other. You can add some `System.out.println()` statements in you main method and you will see that the main threads just starts the next threads. I mean how else would you run multiple threads at the same time, when the main thread has to wait for each sub thread to finish? Doesn't really make sense

Comment: @XtremeBaumer And if that is the case then why didnot the stop() method work before starting the next thread. When I am stopping the thread before starting the next thread then the result donot show even wrong sum.

Comment: `Deprecated.  This method is inherently unsafe. Stopping a thread withThread.stop causes it to unlock all of the monitors that ithas locked (as a natural consequence of the unchecked ThreadDeath exception propagating up the stack). Ifany of the objects previously protected by these monitors were inan inconsistent state, the damaged objects become visible toother threads, potentially resulting in arbitrary behavior. Manyuses of stop should be replaced by code that simplymodifies some variable to indicate that the target thread shouldstop running.`

Comment: `The target thread should check this variableregularly, and return from its run method in an orderly fashionif the variable indicates that it is to stop running. If thetarget thread waits for long periods (on a condition variable,for example), the interrupt method should be used tointerrupt the wait.For more information, see Whyare Thread.stop, Thread.suspend and Thread.resume Deprecated?`